# Call PHP array after it has been populated

Tags: php

I have the following code, that populate an array, which will itself be used to populate a select field :

```
$countries = array();
foreach($cities as $city) {

    $countries[] = $country;
} ?>

<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose country</option>
<?php
foreach($countries as $country){
        echo "<option value='strtolower($country)'>$country</option>";
    }?>
 </select>
```

This works, but my problem is that my select field is located before the first foreach loop (i can't move it since the first foreach does a lot of other things apart from populating the array).
So of course since the array is empty the select field will be too.

How can i solve this?

Comment: just put the populate code above the foreach

Comment: So that first loop produces _output_ already? This is a problem you would not have then, if you followed the [input–process–output (IPO) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model). But if instead of structuring things properly, you rather want a crude workaround - use output buffering then. Output some placeholder _before_ your loop, then you can afterwards get the output buffer content, and _replace_ that placeholder in there.

Comment: What is in $cities? As it doesn't look like it's being used.

Comment: @Searle The first loop ($cities) actually does a lot of stuff, generate a lot of html, but i just simplified for the example. An easy fix would be to change my html so as the select field is after that first loop. I can do that, but I wanted to avoid it and above all i wanted to learn the solution.

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `value='strtolower($country)'>` will not store a lowercase value

Comment: I would suggest that you keep two things separate: 1. connection and preparation of data and 2. creation of visual output.

Comment: Your problem can be completely solved by using a Standard MVC framework design pattern to distinguish data editinf from output. Please [**read about MVC in PHP**](https://www.developerhelps.com/php-mvc-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is top-down and there's no way around that. I'd suggest doing all your PHP coding first and writing code to variables to echo later on. This keeps calculations separate to actual output. For example:

```
$countries = array();
foreach($cities as $city) {

    $countries[] = $country;
}

$html = '<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose country</option>';

foreach($countries as $country){
        $html .= '<option value="' . strtolower($country) . '">' . $country . '</option>';
    }
    
$html .= '</select>';
```

Then when you need it

```
echo $html;
```